# ICU requires intermediate UTF16 conversion step

Tags: utf-8, icu

Why is `libicu` using `utf16` as it's "common denominator" format instead of `utf8`? I need to convert from `utf8` to `utf32` and back and `libicu` seems to make it unnecessarily difficult by requiring this 2 step `utf8->utf16->utf32` conversion, although it's own functions like `u_tolower` also require a `UChar32` input.

It doesn't seem memory is the determining factor here, otherwise they could just use `utf8` for their "base" format as well.

Comment: All UTFs can be converted directly to one another without data loss, but converting one charset  to another requires this 2-step conversion through Unicode, and UTF-16 is easier to work with than UTF-8, and most platforms use UTF-16 for Unicode string processing in memory, whereas UTF-8 is used more for storage and communications (*Nix being an exception to that, as it likes to use UTF-8 in memory, too).  So they likely just kept the same processing model for converting `UTF-8 -> UTF-32` as they do for converting `CharsetX -> CharsetY` for consistency without optimizing where possible.

Comment: you can use `ucnv_fromAlgorithmic` and `ucnv_toAlgorithmic` for more efficient. link: http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/ucnv_8h.html

Answer (score 0):

UTF-16 is the default encoding form of the Unicode Standard, so I suspect that answers the "why" there. See [this ICU page](http://userguide.icu-project.org/unicode) for some additional information.